# Google Chrome sometimes fails to make initial connection or stalls for long time

Tags: networking, google-chrome

I recently moved and after setting up my computer at my new place I noticed that Google Chrome will sometimes stall loading pages. It seems like it's say pages with a lot of content, like Amazon's "Today's Deals" page, but just a guess.

All other pages load fine, like this website. This problem *doesn't* happen in Firefox. If run a speed test (same computer and on my phone) while the problem page is stalling, I'm still getting all 500Mbps that I pay for. When I check the DevTools, I see that the HTTP requests that seem to have the issue either fail to make the initial connection and time out, and in other scenarios, it eventually does make the connection and loads the content, and the network trace logs the wait time under "Stalled"

[Chrome stall and then successful connection screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vILgU.png)

The long download time in that request is new to me. I guess I never waited that long before.

Here's some additional information:

- Same ISP in both homes (Verizon Fios)
- Cleared Cache and Cookies in Chomre
- Reinstalled Chrome
- Disabled all extensions
- I added a small LAN Switch in my network for my PC and PS5. Problems occurs when connected through switch and when directly connected to the router
- No network proxy
- No VPN
- Devices on Wi-Fi, PS5 on ethernet all work without issues
- **Additions (Edit)**:
- TCP/IP Reset

I'd be happy to get any further information and thanks for your time!

---

Edit:

Ran some IPv4 and IPv6 tests at @user1686 's suggestion and IPv4 came back clean but IPv6 had some errors:

- http://icmpcheck.popcount.org/ - Tests Successful
- http://icmpcheckv6.popcount.org/ - MTU Failed [image: MTU failed]
- https://test-ipv6.com/ - Apparently my DNS isn't using IPv6? [image]

Comment: I recently moved   .....  Did you try a TCP/IP Reset?   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer! I did do a DNS flush. But not step 1, I'll try that soon and get back to you! Thanks!

Comment: Hi John, I just gave that a go and no luck. I actually did try that before know that I've seen the output, but I tried again just in case!

I appreciate your answer! If you have any more recommendations, let me know, otherwise, I appreciate the help regardless!

Comment: Are you using any kind of VPN or tunnel? Does Chrome have any extensions installed? Does the same problem happen in MS Edge? Can you check whether http://icmpcheck.popcount.org/ and http://icmpcheckv6.popcount.org/ and https://test-ipv6.com/ report any issues? (Not having IPv6 is not an issue, but if you _do_ have it, good idea to check whether it's working properly.)

Comment: Hello! No VPN is in use, unless Avast did some stuff behind my back lol. Chrome has ublock origin, honey and 1 or 2 others installed, but they are currently disabled as I troubleshoot this issue. I will try full on uninstalling them as well. I will try MS Edge and the URLs Provided and get back to you soon! Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Hello @user1686 I ran multiple tests on those sites and came back with a few errors: I'm updating them in the post now. I appreciate any advice on the results, thanks!

Comment: I have been observing the same issue for many months now, maybe over a year. It happens to a site I use a lot, and it affects both Chrome on Windows and Android, so it's not a fault of any extensions.

Furthermore, if I open an incognito session, the same requests that's currently hanging will succeed there no problem. And if I leave it for a number of minutes, it'll succeed in the main session too, and everything will run smoothly until it happens again. It's really frustrating.

I really do think this is a bug in the Chrome core somewhere, but I don't know how to debug it.